# Programming and Principles chapter 6 Tokens and Calculator

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement, c++14

This is the code set-up:

```
class Token {
public:
char kind;        // what kind of token
double value;     // for numbers: a value 
Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char
    :kind(ch), value(0) { }    
Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
    :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Token_stream {
public: 
Token_stream();   // make a Token_stream that reads from cin
Token get();      // get a Token (get() is defined elsewhere)
void putback(Token t);    // put a Token back
private:
bool full;        // is there a Token in the buffer?
Token buffer;     // here is where we keep a Token put back using putback()
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The constructor just sets full to indicate that the buffer is empty:
Token_stream::Token_stream()
:full(false), buffer(0)    // no Token in buffer
{
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The putback() member function puts its argument back into the Token_stream's buffer:
void Token_stream::putback(Token t)
{
if (full) error("putback() into a full buffer");
buffer = t;       // copy t to buffer
full = true;      // buffer is now full
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Token get()
{
if (full) {       // do we already have a Token ready?  //Syntax error "full" and "buffer" not declared
    // remove token from buffer
    full=false;
    return buffer;
} 

char ch;
cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

switch (ch) {
case ';':    // for "print"
case 'q':    // for "quit"
case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': 
    return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
case '.':
case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
case '5': case '6': case '7': case '9':
    {    
        cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
        return Token('8',val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
    }
  default:
    error("Bad token");
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Token_stream ts;        // provides get() and putback() 

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double expression();    // declaration so that primary() can call expression()

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// deal with numbers and parentheses
double primary()
{
Token t = ts.get();
switch (t.kind) {
case '(':    // handle '(' expression ')'
    {    
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected)");
        return d;
    }
case '8':            // we use '8' to represent a number
    return t.value;  // return the number's value
default:
    error("primary expected");
 }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// deal with *, /, and %
double term()
{
double left = primary();
Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

while(true) {
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '*':
        left *= primary();
        t = ts.get();
    case '/':
        {    
            double d = primary();
            if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
            left /= d; 
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        }
    default: 
        ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
        return left;
    }
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// deal with + and -
double expression()
{
double left = term();      // read and evaluate a Term
Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

while(true) {    
    switch(t.kind) {
    case '+':
        left += term();    // evaluate Term and add
        t = ts.get();
        break;
    case '-':
        left += term();    // evaluate Term and subtract
        t = ts.get();
        break;
    default: 
        ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
        return left;       // finally: no more + or -: return the answer
    }
 }
}
```

I'm having difficulty understanding `expression()`, `term()`, and `primary()`. `Expression()` says that once it reads the token in, if the token is a number, it'll return left, which is `term()`, which then ALSO returns left, which is `primary()`, which finally returns the value of the number itself. However, what I don't understand are the switch cases. `Expression()` states that left = left +/- `term()` but left already exists as `term()` in this case? Wouldn't the code just repeat multiplying, dividing, adding, and subtracting by itself over and over?  The switch cases also never seem to return anything, instead just getting the next token, and finally breaking, after acknowledging that it found an operator and moved on with the calculations, so I'm confused as to how this would present any indication of calculations without something like cout or return?

Comment: Try walking through the code with a debugger. Use input of `2 + 3 * 5`.

Comment: @n.m. The code itself doesn't appear to really have a problem. It should operate just fine as I copied it from the author himself after seeing his work in the book. However, he gives a pretty brief one paragraph explanation on how something like `2 + 3` would act as `Expression() + term()`. It's more a problem on my part, because I feel as if I'm not understanding something extremely basic.

Comment: A debugger is not just for finding bugs. It is a tool that can help you understand how a program works.

Comment: I see. The book hadn't touched much upon debugging yet, so I had no idea. Thank you, I'll try it out later in the morning and maybe I get an inkling of what happened. Hopefully someone else is able to help me dissect the code if that doesn't clear up the problem for me.

Comment: The code is not a program; it seems it's part of one. This could explain why there is not a 'cout' present. About `expression()` and switch cases; have a break, go for a coffee, and bring also paper and a pencil. Ah, in the code there is a `Token get()` function, but I can't see where is `Token Token_stream::get()` defined, it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the switches: they all return a double in the appropriate case and continue consuming and processing in the other (non-error) cases.

About endless loops: `expression()` calls `term()`, `term()` calls `primary()`, primary() calls `expression()` only when it reads an '(' and they all call `get()` to consume the input, so everything is input driven and with valid input (ending with 'q' or ';'), should end with a value after consuming all the input, which is returned by expression().

About left += term(): left is the result of `term()` and after this statement, left is the result of whatever was in left + the result of `term()`, so left is still a number.

One error in the code: `Token get()` should be `Token Token_stream::get()`

Comment: For left += term(), because left is initially the result of term(), wouldn't left + the result of term() just be `term() + term()`?

Comment: It is the result of the addition what the first `term()` returned and what the second `term()` returned.  Both are input driven, so they are different.   In the example `4 * 5 + 3` the first term() returns 20 and the second returns 3, so the result is 23.  In the example `(7 - 3) * 5 + 3`, primary() finds a '(', so it calls expression(), where the first term() returns 7 and the second term() returns 3 and when returning to the first expression, the first term again returns 20.  So basically, it is `term() + term()`, but this should not be confusing.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the second term() is found. So, based on this, let's say `2 + 3`. `Expression()` looks at the value of 2 first, drops all the way to `primary()` and returns the value of 2, because the switch case determined it to be default. Now, `ts.get()` reads in the next token, `+`. Left is found to be initially 3, due to left being equal to `ts.get()` for `term()` and because the token `+` was never placed back. However, when `left += term()` goes through the term function once more, there's no more token to be used because 3 was never put back, and 2 wasn't used.

Comment: `left = term()`, now left is 2, `t = ts.get()`, t is '+', `left += term()` 3 is added to left, so it is 5. These are the only places in `expression()` where input is retrieved.  You should really try to follow it with a debugger to see it for yourself.